# Mismatch of argument count in a Python error with PrettyTable

Tags: python, oop

I have used PrettyTable with Python3 for a short while, but now stucked in integrating it as a member object to a class.

Consider the following constructor code for a table with 4 columns:

```
columns=["A","B","C","D"]
self.t_report = PrettyTable(columns)
self.t_report.add_row("a","b","c","d")
```

Python error message:

```
TypeError: add_row() takes 2 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

How comes this 2:5 while I define 4:4?

Comment: Does `self.t_report.add_row(["a","b","c","d"])` work? Provide a list, instead of individual items?

Comment: For what it's worth: the last version of PrettyTable seems to have come out in February 2013, and barely supports Python 3; its homepage has also disappeared. You may want to try to use another package for working with tabular data. Pandas is pretty much the standard nowadays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```
self.t_report.add_row("a","b","c","d")
```

with

```
self.t_report.add_row(["a","b","c","d"])
```

Answer (score 0):

`self.t_report.add_row(["a","b","c","d"])`